# Receive a graph from php based on the input

Tags: php, mysql, charts, google-visualization

I am very new to php and I am trying to show some specific records based on a input (from drop down).
From Customer.php page I am selecting a customer which will send a request to analysis.php which will perform DB operations and displays results in a tabular format. Now I am trying to draw a graph using the results from DB.

I donno where to start, any help would be much appreciated.

Below is my code.
customer.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Customer</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateBox(){
        var customer_name = document.getElementById('customer_name').value;
         if(customer_name.length == 0){
            alert("Please select customer name");
            return false;
            //handle validation response here
        } else { 

            //document.getElementById("form").submit();//submit form, or whatever the button is supposed to do...
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","analysis.php?q="+customer_name,true);
        xmlhttp.send();         
        }

    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form class="form" id="form" method="post">
<table align="center">
<tr>
<td>
<label>Customer Name :</label></td>
<td><select name="customer_name" id="customer_name" required>
 <option value="">Select</option> 
<option value="Dell">Dell</option>
<option value="HP">HP</option>
<option value="Lenovo">Lenovo</option>
<option value="Compaq">Compaq</option>
</select></td></tr>

<td><input  onclick="validateBox()" type="button" name="addrecord" value="Begin Analysis"></td></table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and analysis.php looks like

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
$db = mysql_select_db("db", $connection);
$q = $_GET['q'];
$resource=array();
$z=0;
$SQL = mysql_query("select resources from users ", $connection);
while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($SQL)) {
    $a = $db_field['resources'];
    $resource[$z] = $a;
    $z++;
}
$resourcelength = count($resource);
?>
<table border = "2" width = "30%" align='center'>
<tr align ="center">
    <th >resource</th>
    <th ># Count</th>
<?php
for($x = 0; $x < $resourcelength; $x++) {
    print("<tr>");
    print("<td align = 'center'>$resource[$x]</td>");
    $y=$resource[$x];
    $SQL = mysql_query("SELECT count(distinct(ticket_id)) as total FROM tickets WHERE resource_name='".$y."' ", $connection);
        while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($SQL)) {
            $a = $db_field['total'];
                print("<td align = 'center'>$a</td>");  
        }   
    print("</tr>");
}
?>
</table>
```

and the output will be like

```
Resource    Total
A   30
B   12
C   15
D   0
X   13
```

I want to convert this to a graph, I tried to include google charts, but no luck.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use [pChart](http://pchart.sourceforge.net). It's a free PHP library, really easy to use and it contains [a lot of basic examples](http://pchart.sourceforge.net/documentation.php?topic=exemple13).